# Objects in Array are not being replaced by new Objects

Tags: c++

This has been driving me insane for hours - I'm new to C++: I can't figure out why my programs thinks I want it do this.

I have a class `House`

```cpp
class House{

    private: 
        int number;
        std::string family;
    
    public:
    
        House(int n, std::string f){
            
            this->number = n;
            this->family = f;
            
        }
        
        House(){
        
            this->number = 0;
            this->family = "unassigned";
        
        }
        
        void whoLivesHere(){
        
            std::cout<<"The"<<family<<"lives here."<<std::endl;
        
        }


};
```

I have another class `Neighborhood`

```cpp
class Neighborhood{
    private:
        int size;
        House houses[100];
    
    public:
    
        Neighborhood(){
        
            this->size=0;

        }
        
        void addHouse(House h){
        
            this->houses[this->size] = h;
            this->size++;
            
        }
        
        void whoLivesHere(){
        
            for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++){
                this->houses[this->size].whoLivesHere();
            }
        
        }
    
    
};
```

And this is what is happening on my `main`.

```
int main(){

    Neighborhood n1;
    House h1(1,"Johnsons");
    House h2(1,"Jones");
    n1.addHouse(h1);
    n1.addHouse(h2);
    
    n1.whoLivesHere();
    
    return 0;
}
```

And what I get on the Terminal is this.

> The unassigned lives here

> The unassigned lives here

> The unassigned lives here

1. Why didn't the new objects replace the first two default objects?
2. Why show three objects? If `size` should be `1`.

Thank you tonnes in advance!

Comment: `this->houses[this->size].whoLivesHere()`? Please try to explain that to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: You don't need all those `this->` to refer to member variables, fyi.

Comment: Also, with the `addHouse` function you show us, then `size` should be equal to `2`, not `1` or `3`. Which means the claimed output doesn't match the code you show, meaning it's not really a [mcve].

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing the behavior where it shows three objects. When I compile and run this code, it prints two lines as expected.

Comment: So, this is both a simple typo, and not reproducible. Two for the price of one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm trying to get every house in the houses array in neighborhood to call their whoLivesHere method :

Comment: @NathanPierson noted! won't have to type as much :)) i'm sorry yes, its printing out two lines, but it is still printing the default family name instead of the objects name :/

Comment: @bettyfromthelakes `trying to get every house in the houses array` Right. That's what the `for(int i=0; i<size; i++)` loop was meant to do. Now ask yourself, where is the house number `i` used in that loop.

Comment: In `this->houses[this->size]`, what is `this->size` doing? Will the index `this->size` be different in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: wow @Someprogrammerdude and dxiv i can't believe that slipped my mind! THANK YOU, i got totally played by size++;

Answer (score 2):

You can make short work of this problem by using the tools the C++ Standard Library gives you, like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector<House> neighborhood;

  // emplace_back() forwards arguments to the constructor
  neighborhood.emplace_back(1, "Johnson");
  neighborhood.emplace_back(2, "Jones");

  // No need to track size, std::vector does that for you: size(),
  // but that's not even needed to iterate, you can just do this:
  for (auto& house : neighborhood) {
    house.whoLivesHere();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here I've cleaned up your House implementation:

```cpp
class House {
private:
  int number;
  std::string family;

public:
  // Tip: Use constructor lists
  House(int n, const std::string& f) : number(n), family(f) { };

  // Useful even for defaults
  House() : number(0), family("unassigned") { };

  // Flag methods that don't modify anything as const
  void whoLivesHere() const {
    std::cout << "The " << family << " lives here at number " << number << "." << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into using vectors next time :)